# discord.js .msg.channel.send().then promise not working

Tags: promise, discord.js, bots, loading

So this is my code for sending an embed, that says Loading shop with the dots changing. However, I am getting a pretty strange error message, which first tells me the error is at msg.delete() with "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined" and then a second one at the second msg.edit() saying "Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined". I searched up the docs and many forums, but the .then() syntax should be right. Any idea?

```
var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor("GOLD").setTitle("Loading shop");
    msg.channel.send(embed)
        .then(msg => {setTimeout(()=>{msg.edit(embed.setTitle("Loading shop."))}, 500)})
        .then(msg => {setTimeout(()=>{msg.edit(embed.setTitle("Loading shop.."))}, 500)})
        .then(msg => {setTimeout(()=>{msg.edit(embed.setTitle("Loading shop..."))}, 500)})
        .then(msg => {setTimeout(()=>{msg.edit(embed.setTitle("Loading shop"))}, 500)})
        .then(msg => {setTimeout(()=>{msg.edit(embed.setTitle("Loading shop."))}, 500)})
        .then(msg => {setTimeout(()=>{msg.edit(embed.setTitle("Loading shop.."))}, 500)})
        .then(msg => {setTimeout(()=>{msg.edit(embed.setTitle("Loading shop..."))}, 500)})
        .then(msg => {msg.delete()});
```

Comment: `then` chains to the next `then` with its return value - so you'd need to `return msg` after each of those `setTimeout`s

Comment: Or don't take a `msg` parameter if you want to get `msg` from the closure as it's likely available - so `msg =>` just becomes `() => `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem as follows. The `setTimeout` is not getting handled well with promises so I searched up the solution.

```
function delay(t, v) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, v), t)
  });
}

Promise.prototype.delay = function(t) {
  return this.then(function(v) {
    return delay(t, v);
  });
}

var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor("GOLD").setTitle("Loading shop");
msg.channel.send(embed)
  .delay(500).then(msg => msg.edit(embed.setTitle("Loading shop.")))
  .delay(500).then(msg => msg.edit(embed.setTitle("Loading shop..")))
  .delay(500).then(msg => msg.edit(embed.setTitle("Loading shop...")))
  .delay(500).then(msg => msg.delete());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use this all "thens"
2. Use await

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor("GOLD").setTitle("Loading shop");
  const msg = message.channel.send(embed); // i change to message because msg will be used as var name
        setTimeout(() => {
      // do stuff
      msg.edit(embed.setTitle("Loading shop.")); // etc..
}, 500);
```